# toggle to show .not() hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, hide, show

i have a table with some events, the visible rows have a `new` class and all of the past events are hidden with a `:not' function.

i want to make a button with an `onClick` function that enables users to see past events that don't have the `new` class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('tbody tr:not(.new)').hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<tbody>
  <table style="width:100%" cellpadding="8px">

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</tbody>

</html>
```

Comment: What help do you need, what problems are you having? Where did you get stuck when you made your attempts?

Comment: @David Thomas my actual code has more id's and classes than this, there were some console errors re:functions not being defined but everything is working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to **replace** the new events with the old events, the best way to go about this would be to show **all** elements on the click of the button, and then hide the `new` elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody tr:not(.new)').hide();
});

function showOld() {
  $('tbody tr').show();
  $('tbody tr.new').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="showOld()">Show Old Events</button>

<tbody>
  <table style="width:100%" cellpadding="8px">
    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</tbody>
```

To show the new elements in addition to the old elements, simply remove:

`$('tbody tr.new').hide();`

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: wasn't aware that the .show() function would work. i thought i had to specifically target the unclassified rows or else they would be ignored in jquery! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems very trivial, is that what you expect?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody tr:not(.new)').hide();
});

$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('tbody tr').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<tbody>
  <table style="width:100%" cellpadding="8px">

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</tbody>

<button id='btn'>click</button>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just flipped the sense of what you were doing initially, and added a button to activate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('tbody tr:not(.new)').hide();
  
  $('button').click( function() {
    $('tbody tr:not(.new)').show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<tbody>
  <table style="width:100%" cellpadding="8px">

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</tbody>
<button>Show Old Events</button>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add button and on click show all row and and change the text of button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('tbody tr:not(.new)').hide();
  
  $('#show_past_event').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("all_events"))
    {
      $('tbody tr:not(.new)').hide();
      $(this).text("Show Past Event");
      $('#show_past_event').removeClass("all_events");
    }
    else
    {
      $('tbody tr').show();
      $(this).text("Hide Past Event");
      $('#show_past_event').addClass("all_events");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<tbody>

   <button id="show_past_event">Show Past Event</button>

  <table style="width:100%" cellpadding="8px">

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>old event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="new">
      <td>new event</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</tbody>

</html>
```

Comment: You could make it a better by explaining your answer